# For all sets A,B, and C, If B ∩ C ⊆ A, then (A-B) ∩ (A-C) ≠∅

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m having trouble working in the following subset proof:

For all sets A,B, and C, If $\varnothing\ne B ∩ C ⊆ A$, then (A-B) ∩ (A-C)  ≠∅

My train of thought of creating a proof of via the following. Am I headed towards the right direction or am I making a mistake in my proofs?

Assuming B ∩ C ⊆ A
X exists in B and X exists in C
If x doesn’t exist in b or C then x doesn’t exist in A
Hence x doesnt in B(universal)  and x doesn’t exist in C universal and does not exist in A(universal)
Equivalentelty x doesn’t exist in A-B and x doesn’t exist in A-C
Or equivalently, (A-B) ∩ (A-C) )  ≠∅

Comment: That is wrong. Take $A=B=C=\emptyset$.

Comment: You might want to learn `\setminus`,  `\cap`,  `\neq`,  `\emptyset`.

Comment: @Parcly: Really? [set-theory]?

Answer (score 1):

That is wrong. Take $A=B=C=\emptyset$.

It becomes true if you replace the hypothesis by $$B\cup C\subsetneq A$$ because then $$(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)=A\setminus(B\cup C)\neq \emptyset$$

Comment: No, even with $\subsetneq$ in the hypothesis it's still wrong. Take $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1\}$, and $C=\{2\}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, if you take $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{1,3\}$ and $C=\{2,3\}$, you even get $B \cap C \neq \emptyset$, which the questioner assumed.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks. Corrected (typoed $\cap$ instead of $\cup$).

Comment: Ah. So I think I understand it now. Here’s my attempt at a proof by contradiction. If B ∩ C ⊆A, then (A-B) ∩ (A-C) ≠∅.
Suppose not, so let (A-B) ∩ (A-C).
Then x exists in A and x does not in exist in B and x does not exist in C.
But because assume x exists B ∩ C( as B ∩ C ⊆ A). We have a contradiction. Thus B ∩ C ≠∅.

Comment: @Jlee First of all, you say "$x$ lies in $A$" for $x\in A$, not "$x$ exists $A$". Also, your last argument doesn't make sense. If you assumed that $x\in A\setminus (B \cup C)$, then there is no reason for $x$ to be in $B \cap X$. In principle, you will have a hard day to show something if someone already proved that the claim is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Let $$A=B\cap C$$ or even $$A=B$$ an example is $$B=\{1,2\}\\C=\{2,3\}\\A=\{2\}$$

Comment: How would I find the solution from A = B ∩ C? The numerical set made sense but I’m not sure where to start my proof

Comment: The point is, that if $A=B \cap C$, then your statement is wrong (if $A\neq \emptyset$). If $A=B\cap C$, then $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq C$, so $A\setminus B=\emptyset=A\setminus C$, so the intersection of both is empty aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_{alone} = A- (B\cup C)$ which consists of all the elements of $A$ but none of the elements of $B$ or $C$.

$A_{in B} = A\cap B\cap C^c$ which consists of all the elements of $A$ that are in $B$ but none of the elements of $C$.

$A_{in C} = A\cap C\cap B^c$ which consists of all the elements of $A$ that are in $C$ but none of the elements of $B$.

$A_{inallthree} = A\cap B \cap C$.

Let $B_{alone} = B- (A\cup C)$ which consists of all the elements of $B$ but none of the elements of $A$ or $C$.

$B_{A} = A_{in B} = A\cap B\cap C^c$ which consists of all the elements of $B$ that are in $A$ but none of the elements of $C$.

$B_{in C} = B\cap C\cap A^c$ which consists of all the elements of $B$ that are in $C$ but none of the elements of $A$.

$B_{inallthree} = A_{inallthree} = A\cap B \cap C$.

Let $C_{alone} = C- (A\cup B)$ which consists of all the elements of $C$ but none of the elements of $A$ or $B$.

$C_{A} = A_{in C} = A\cap C\cap B^c$ which consists of all the elements of $C$ that are in $A$ but none of the elements of $B$.

$C_{in B} =B_{in C} =  B\cap C\cap A^c$ which consists of all the elements of $C$ that are in $B$ but none of the elements of $A$.

$C_{inallthree} =B_{inallthree}=  A_{inallthree} = A\cap B \cap C$.

These seven distinct sets are disjoint and partition the universal $A\cup B \cup C$.[1]

=====

So you are given:

$\emptyset\ne B ∩ C ⊆ A$

$\emptyset \ne (B_{alone} \cup B_{inA}\cup B_{in C} \cup B_{inallthree})\cap (C_{alone} \cup C_{inA}\cup C_{in B} \cup C_{inallthree})\subset (A_{alone} \cup A_{inB}\cup A_{in B} \cup A_{inallthree})$

$\emptyset \ne ( B_{in C} \cup B_{inallthree}) \subset (A_{alone} \cup A_{inB}\cup A_{in B} \cup A_{inallthree})$

Which means $\cup B_{in C} = \emptyset$ and $A\cap B\cap C \ne \emptyset$.

That's .... all we can conclude.

Now: $(A-B)\cap(A-C)=$

$(A_{alone}\cup A_{inC})\cap (A_{alone}\cup A_{in B})=$

$A_{alone}$.

There is simply no reason $A_{alone}$ can't be empty.  And there is also no reason it should.  It could go either way.

So as a counter example let:

$A_{alone} = \emptyset; A_{in B}=\{ab\}; A_{in C} = \{ac\}, A_{inallthree} = \{abc\}; B_{alone}=\{b\}; B_{inC} = \emptyset; C_{alone} = \{c\}$.

i.e. $A =\{ab,ac,abc\}; B= \{b,ab,abc\}; C= \{c,ac,abc\}$.

Then $\emptyset \ne B\cap C = \{abc\} \subset A$.

And $(A-B)\cap (A-C) = \{ac\}\cap \{ab\} = \emptyset$.

=======

[1] A Venn diagram of the three sets will cut that universe into $2^3 = 8$ distinct disjoint subsets.  The eighth one, that I did not mention would be $N_{none} = (A\cup B\cup C)^c$.  It's not relevant.