# Prove for all sets A, B and C, if (B ∩ C) ⊆ A, then (A-B) ∩ (A-C) ≠ ∅

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

This question was previously asked here: [For all sets A,B, and C, If B ∩ C ⊆ A, then (A-B) ∩ (A-C) ≠∅](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860480/for-all-sets-a-b-and-c-if-b-%E2%88%A9-c-%E2%8A%86-a-then-a-b-%E2%88%A9-a-c-%E2%89%A0%E2%88%85)

However, it didn't help me much so I wanted if someone could verify my working and correct me where I am wrong.

**My initial question is:**
For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, if $(B ∩ C) ⊆ A$, then $(A-B) ∩ (A-C) ≠ ∅$

I know this is true by drawing a Venn Diagram.

***Proof:***
$(B ∩ C) ⊆ A$

$x∈(B∩C)⇒x∈A$

$x∈(B∩C)^c ∩ A$

$x∈A∩(B^c∩C^c)$

$x∈(A∩B^c)∩(A∩C^c)$

Which is $(A-B)∩(A−C)≠∅$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why is the third step of your proof true?

Comment: this fails if $A=B=C$

Comment: The statement is not true as written. It is true if $(B\cap C) \subsetneq A$.

Comment: How can I write a counter example for this. I am very confused :( @kccu

Comment: @ZahirSher Look at the comment above mine.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is *not true*. For example, take $A = B=C$ then $B \cap C = A$, however $A - B$ and $A-C$ are both empty (Thank you to gt6989b above!).

In your proof, the step $x \in (B \cap C) \implies x \in A$ is correct, but the next,namely the third step is unclear i.e. how was $x$ in $B \cap C$ in statement $2$, and how did it land up in the complement in statement $3$. Also, in the fourth step, $(B \cap C)^c \neq (B^c \color{red}{\cap} C^c)$, but instead equals $B^c \color{blue}{\cup} C^c$, so the fifth step also goes wrong.

The result is not true even after assuming that $B \cap C$ is strictly contained in $A$. Indeed, let $A = C = \{1,2\} $ and $B = \{1\}$, then $A-C$ is empty so the intersection with $A-B$ is empty, although $B \cap C = B$ is strictly contained in $A$. Modifications have to be made to the given statement to make it true.